# readLines() webscraping cannot open connection in r

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am using Windows 7 with R3.3.1. I have a data frame called `idsFinal_Attack` that has two columns.

```
Attack Type   
1                                                    40674 
2 Netcore.Netis.Devices.Hardcoded.Password.Security.Bypass 
3                                  DNS.Invalid.Size.Attack  
4                       Acunetix.Web.Vulnerability.Scanner  
5                                   SIPVicious.SIP.Scanner  
6                                                    17799   
New
1                                   SIPVicious.SIP.Scanner
2 Netcore.Netis.Devices.Hardcoded.Password.Security.Bypass
3                                  DNS.Invalid.Size.Attack
4                       Acunetix.Web.Vulnerability.Scanner
5                                   SIPVicious.SIP.Scanner
6                               MS.SMBv2.Infinite.Loop.DoS
```

The first is "Attack Type" consisting of both character and numeric ID's. The second column is what I wish to fill in with the code below.

```
URL = 'http://www.fortinet.com/ids/VID'
idsFinal_Attack$New = character(length = nrow(idsFinal_Attack))

for (i in 1:nrow(idsFinal_Attack)) {
    if (is.na(as.numeric(idsFinal_Attack$`Attack Type`[i]))) {
            idsFinal_Attack$New[i] = idsFinal_Attack$`Attack Type`[i]
    } else {
            fortinetPage = readLines(paste0(URL, idsFinal_Attack$`Attack Type`[i]))
            fortinetPage = grep("id=\"ency_title\">Vulnerability:", fortinetPage, 
                                value = TRUE)
            idsFinal_Attack$New[i] = 
                    gsub("<h1 id=\"ency_title\">Vulnerability: |</h1>", "", fortinetPage)
    }
}
```

For rows in "Attack Type" that contain a character string, I wish to copy and paste that string into the adjacent cell of column "New". For rows in "Attack Type" that contain numeric entries, like row 1, I wish to paste that numeric value to the end of variable "URL", then use the `readLines()` function to extract a portion of the webpage that the augmented "URL" variable takes me to, i.e. http://www.fortinet.com/ids/VID40674. I only need a small section of the webpage titled "Vulnerability" with the subsequent text. `readLines()` returns all the text from the webpage, and then I can use grep and gsub to get the desired section. The data frame `idsFinal_Attack` has 145 rows, 67 of which are numeric and will require a readLines() command. The code below works for about half of them, and then throws the error shown below.

> ```
> Error in readLines(url(paste0(URL, idsFinal_Attack$`Attack Type`[i]), 
> :  cannot open the connection
> ```

This is my first attempt, and I realize the code can be made more concise. I just wanted to get a working version. I have briefly experimented with the XML and rvest packages, but have not had any lucky. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. Use an HTML parser like `rvest` or `XML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `readLines` may not appropriately handle redirects. Since Fortinet redirects, you may run into trouble.

I believe that using `rvest` is more transparent than using `readLines`.

For instance, a reproducible example is:

```
library(readr)
library(rvest)

sample.data <- "Attack Type New
40674   SIPVicious.SIP.Scanner
Netcore.Netis.Devices.Hardcoded.Password.Security.Bypass    Netcore.Netis.Devices.Hardcoded.Password.Security.Bypass
DNS.Invalid.Size.Attack DNS.Invalid.Size.Attack
Acunetix.Web.Vulnerability.Scanner  Acunetix.Web.Vulnerability.Scanner
SIPVicious.SIP.Scanner  SIPVicious.SIP.Scanner
17799   MS.SMBv2.Infinite.Loop.DoS
127 MS.SMBv2.Infinite.Loop.DoS"

idsFinal_Attack <- read_tsv(sample.data)

URL = 'http://www.fortinet.com/ids/VID'
idsFinal_Attack$New = character(length = nrow(idsFinal_Attack))

for (i in 1:nrow(idsFinal_Attack)) {
  attack.type <- idsFinal_Attack$`Attack Type`[i]
  not.fortinet.id <- is.na(as.numeric(attack.type))
  if (not.fortinet.id) {
    idsFinal_Attack$New[i] = attack.type
  } else {
    fortinet.url <- paste0(URL, attack.type)
    fortinet.page <- try(read_html(fortinet.url))
    if ("try-error" %in% class(fortinet.page)){
      idsFinal_Attack$New[i] <- NA
      next;
    }
    title <- fortinet.page %>%
      html_node(xpath = ".//*[@id='ency_title']") %>%
      html_text()
    title.clean <- gsub("^\\w+:\\s+", "", title)
    idsFinal_Attack$New[i] <- title.clean  
  }
}
```

Comment: is the "read_tsv" function supposed to recreate the "idsFinal_Attack" data frame that I originally posted?

Comment: using the original idsFinal_Attack data frame, your solution worked perfectly for all URL's that mapped to a webpage. However, there was one (http://www.fortinet.com/ids/VID127) that threw the following error:    "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.". The reason, i think, is because "The Page Was Not Found". This happened in the middle of the code execution and caused the code to stop executing with 80 rows left. Is there a way to work around this so the code continues to run and a message like "unresolved" is placed in the cell where the web data should have gone?

Comment: Good call. I've added a `try` test to see if the `read_html` fails and, if so, populate the `New` column with a `NA` value. Does that work?

Comment: It worked! your coding technique and use of descriptive variable names is something i need to strive for. Definitely more logical and readable. The last concern I have is over the following line: html_node(xpath = ".//*[@id='ency_title']"). I read that // references any node and the [@id=`ency_title`] is a node with attribute name. However, I can't make sense of the use of the . and *. Also, I came across the "id=ency_title" by right clicking on that portion of the webpage and combing through the html. Is there a quicker way of identifying the node that contains the desired data?

Comment: Also, I received a message saying: Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (http://www.fortinet.com/ids/VID127) about 10 min after running the code. The didnt appear  until I ran another piece of code. Should I put a line in there to close the connection?

Comment: Great! The `*` in the XPath expression matches "any node" i.e. not just `div` or `span` or `h1`. It matches your original code more closely. The dot (`.`) and `//` match any node in the hierarchy. As for a faster way - yes. See the [SelectorGadget package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html). I usually use XPath because I'm more familiar, but CSS selectors are great. Finally, I wouldn't worry about the unused connection message unless you're doing *a lot* of them.